# How to change the title on Purchase Order in Checkout?

Tags: magento2, purchase-order

I want to be able to replace "Purchase Order Number" to just "Order Number", I couldn't find the right phtml file that handles this.

[image]

Does anyone know what is the right `phtml` or `html` file, so I can change the wordings? Thank you.

Comment: Is any solution worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use translation i18n to change the label. Please follow this [link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_practice.html)

In your `i18n/en_US.csv` file translate the purchase order number with your required label.

```
"Purchase Order Number", "Your Custom Label"
```

After this run setup upgrade, compile and deploy your setup.

Answer (score 0):

The original template can be found on below path

> vendor/magento/module-purchase-order/view/frontend/web/template/payment/companycredit-form.html

The default text should be "Custom Reference Number".

But possibly in your case template is already overridden or text is being changed using translation csv. Check is there any override or translation already exists in your case. And update accordingly.